# Negative form of "Here comes the guy"

Tags: negation, subject-verb-inversion

Consider the sentence:

> Here comes the guy.

What would be the best negative form of this sentence--not normal negative like "The guy doesn't come here", but both inverted and negative?

One possibility is:

> Not here comes the guy.

in the sense that *Not here* is used as an adverb clause and the positions of subject and verb are switched. Does that sound right or is there a better way to have both negation and inversion?

Comment: Mr. Anderson would say: "There IS no rainbow!"

Comment: There comes no rainbow.

Comment: There no guy comes

Comment: @petershor Yes, if the subject isn't specified. But what if the subject is specified? (I changed the subject from rainbow to guy because it might confuse)

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, but that's a different *there* though!

Comment: *Oh, somewhere in this favored land the sun is shining high; the band is playing somewhere, and somewhere comes the guy.*

Comment: Going by the comments and answers so far, this is quite a mess. The answer is, obviously, "there doesn't come the guy" (when talking about a specific guy, which is what you're after), or "there comes no guy" (when we're not talking about a specific guy). Everything else on this page is pointless filler and is bound to confuse future readers. It must either be weeded out, or the question has to be asked anew in a more clear manner.

Comment: What do you want? *"that's not where the guy comes; he comes somewhere else"*; *"there isn't any guy coming; I was led to expect somebody"*; *"the guy said he'd be coming there, but he probably got confused and showed up elsewhere"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final structure may depend on which aspect of the idea you wish to negate.

Is the rainbow not coming as expected?

> There doesn't come the rainbow (as it stayed in Duluth).

Or is it not a rainbow that's coming, but something else?

> There comes not the rainbow (but my dog Uncouth).

Answer (score 1):

In AmE, we usually say "here comes..." and "*there* goes...".

The negative to "*Here* comes the guy," could be:

"The guy hasn't come."

"The guy isn't here/there."

Or, (in the common parlance) "Where the hell is this &*%# guy?"

(You could also substitute "elevator" for "guy" in your example)

Answer (score 0):

There the rainbow fails to come.

There the rainbow comes. Not.

Comment: Why are these good suggestions?